# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 22 declared in library

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, android-min-sdk

Earlier we were using Android API level 28 with minSdkVersion as 19 in config.xml and the app was available in the play store. Recently we updated the android version ( By removing and adding latest android as google play console mandated to have android above API level 29 ). Bu doing this ionic build gave below error  :

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 22 declared in library [:CordovaLib] D:\MobileApp\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
            Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
                    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 22,
                    or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Due to this app could be updated in could of mobile phones. Please suggest if there is any way to have 19 as minSdkVersion.

Thanks !

Comment: Add `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />` in your config.xml

Comment: I added this and the build is running on mobiles with API level >= 22 however Few mobiles are having lower android version and hence not able to make use of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the minSDKVersion to **22** in your config.xml file. I think the problem will be resolved. I had the same problem.

Example: `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />`

Comment: And how it helps to support 19 sdk?

Comment: Does anyone no what to change this Jan 2022?

I can find nothing searching the android project nor the entire ionic project that lists 
<preference ...> anything
{proj}/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml contains only 
<widget ...>
   <access ... />
</widget>

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, it's not very complicated :

Enter on "player settings" (file --> build settings --> player settings) and scroll.

When you see "Minimum API Level", chante that (i choice Android 8.0 "Oreo" (API Level 26)).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this 1 line code below, under Gradle Scripts > **gradle.properties (Project Properties)** > Syn now > Build (Clean project > Rebuild project)

```
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32
```